# Can I View Search Engine Referred Pages In AWStats?

Tags: logging, statistics, cpanel, awstats, visitor-statistic

By default, AWStats shows the search engine referrals by number. It shows the phrases. And, it shows the content hits. However, I'm looking to view only the pages that received traffic from a search engine.

[image: AWStats search engine referred]

In this case, I would like to see the 1567 pages that were referred to and how many hits each one has.

I have tried doing several way with the default AWStats, but it is not possible out of the box.

Does anyone know a way to customize AWStats to get this data? If you could point me in the right direction of a script to write or customization I could make, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: AWStats not have such option but Google analytics have such option

Comment: Hey Shiv, yes, that's correct. Unfortunately, I can't use Google analytics for this website. I'm hoping that someone will know how to extract the data from AWStats. It's in the logs, so we should be able to view it using some programming. A question upvote would help get some visibility though.